# Make two virtual machines ping in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ping

I'm trying to make two virtual machines communicate in Virtual Box, but without any success.

Here are the steps I have done:

1. I set both VMs in Internal networking mode (using `VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --nic<x> intnet`)
2. I set the DHCP server that is built into VirtualBox to manage IP addresses :`VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname intnet --ip 10.13.13.100 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 10.13.13.101 --upperip 10.13.13.254 --enable`

But then both VMs have the same IP address (10.13.13.101) and even if I set the IP manually, the Virtual Machines are not pinging each other.

Answer (score 0):

My bad both of the VMs had the same MAC address!